# Ionic Button with icon instead of Text

Tags: ionic-framework

I would like to have the "ion-android-sync" icon (http://ionicons.com)
My current code is

```
<button class="button" ng-click="loadEvents()">L</button>
```

What's the proper class structure for that?

Also, if I just load the css file advertised on ionicons.com is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ion-icon element to use ionic icons inside button.
I hope it will reach your requirement

for example, i will add facebook logo inside button

```
 <button class="button" ng-click="loadEvents()"><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></button>
```